# In Dired, how can I color the names of files younger than 1 hour?

Tags: dired

windows 10, Emacs 26.1 , Dired+

I install dired+ from here

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus

Here example of some dir in the dired+ mode

[image]

Is it possible to change color of file names that not older than one hour?

In this example this is a two files:

```
get_room_by_id_response.json

create_dummy_room_response.json
```

Comment: With lisp almost anything is possible. ;-) But please clarify what you mean by "younger" (not older than). File creation time? Last modification time?

Comment: There's also just sorting by time (`s`). (And since you apparently use Dired+, see also `C-x D R` (`diredp-recent-files`).)

Comment: @Drew Last modification time

Comment: @Drew I use sort  by time (s), but change color is also very help

Comment: @Drew I'm not found diredp-recent-files. I found only diredp-dired-recent-dirs

Comment: @Drew you can have a look at https://github.com/syohex/emacs-dired-k

Comment: Please put the info about mod time in the question itself. Comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `diredp-dired-recent-files`, not `diredp-recent-files`. (The former is a command, bound to `C-x D R`; the latter is a helper functions.) And perhaps you need to update your version of Dired+.

Comment: @djangoliv: It sounds like OP can just use `dired-k.el` to get what he wants. If so, you can provide that as an answer. AFAICT, one can use `dired-k.el` together with Dired+ - that seems to work OK (with minimal testing).

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/syohex/emacs-dired-k .
By default, dates are fade with age.

As @Drew said (Thanks), you can use dired-k.el together with Dired+.